# I accepted a position for after I graduate (6 months away), and then Google calls?

Tags: job-offer, job-acceptance

I've been interning at my current workplace for a year and they offered me a full time position after I graduate, which is 6 months away. I weighed the pros and cons, and even though it's not exactly the job I want I thought that at least I will have a job secured after I graduate so I can comfortably figure out exactly where I want to go and what I want to do.

Then a few weeks after accepting I get an e-mail from Google saying they saw my profile and have a phone interview with them. I will be a comsci grad so working at Google would be a dream come true, and something I never expected. But during the interview they said they may not be able to continue because I have accepted the other position already. But the position I accepted, although it is in writing,(I always read what I sign) and it is not a promised contract, it basically stipulates either end can cancel the offer at any time.

My question is, what would you do in this situation? Have you been in a similar situation? Do you think it's wrong for me to look for another job after accepting an offer 6 months away? I never thought I was doing something wrong and thought it was common to continue looking if the job is so far in the future, especially with the job market today.Overall if I had known I wouldn't be able to apply for other jobs after accepting this job after graduation then I don't think I would have accepted the position..

Comment: Related: [Exploding offer season](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/11/26.html)

Comment: We can't tell you what to do, but if you want to recast your final paragraph as a more answerable question, you can [edit] your question and that will put it into the review queue for possible reopening.  Maybe your question is "how should I continue interviewing when I have accepted another offer"?  (Though if either side can cancel, how much of an offer is it?)

Comment: Same thing happened to me (and it happens to thousands of people every year). Just do the interview, it won't hurt. And if you do get an offer from Google, I think you can safely expect that first company will at least understand that you have a "good reason" to drop them.

Answer (score 9):

I interviewed with Google several times. The first three interviews are tough because that's what they use to screen away the candidates, so I suggest that you go through the experience so that you know what's in store for you. I have to say that I improved as a systems engineer as a result of this experience. If man bites dog and you get an offer from Google ... well, we'll worry about that bridge when we are close enough to cross it. I'd say, give it your best shot because the odds of passing are not high - shall we say, 5% or less - and if you don't pass, your dilemma takes care of itself. Right?

Comment: +1 yes, typically people take 3 interviews to work at google (i mean, they fail the first two), so OP should *definitely* take the interview.

Comment: 5 times and still pending.  They're definitely interested tho!

Comment: @Miro One more interview to go - Congrats and good luck, you are a hotshot! :)

Answer (score 6):

The company you signed with is obviously not going to be happy, but you should act in your best interest. If Google is what you want, then you should probably go after them.

Even if there is some clause in the contract that states that you have to pay some fine (or something) for breaking the contract, if you can handle it, then why not pursue your dreams?

Also, I seem to understand that you currently don't have a job offer from Google. Then why the dilemma? There's always a chance that they don't accept you. I'd worry about it when I actually have something concrete in hand.

Answer (score 0):

Since it says in your contract that either party can cancel at any time, you can leave the offer for your current job with no problem, if Google hired you.

Do not do anything right now. The Google interviews are brain surgery hard, and the chances of you getting in are not likely unless you are a genius pretty much. I personally plan to work as an engineer for a few years until I understand programming much more before I even attempt it.